# Can't define date type index on elastisearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch, indexing

I've got a document sent to elasticsearch that looks something like this:

```
{
    "created": 1543247749419,
    "name": "something",
    "person": {
        "created": 1543247012491,
        ...
    }
}
```

Both `created` fields are `epoch_millis` date format (Timestamp in milliseconds). I tried basically 3 things:

1. Add the document using curl like this:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "http://ipaddress:9200/somedb" -d "@/some/path"`

So far so good, but the index set the type of my `created` as `long`, not `date`.

2. Copy the index from the Kibana interface, change the `long` for `date` and create a new db for it:

   {
       "mapping": {
           "somedb2": { 
               "properties": { 
                   "created": { 
                       "type": "date",
                       "format": "x"
                   },

and send the data like this:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "http://ipaddress:9200/somedb2" -d "@/some/path"`

Then I received this error message from elasticsearch

```
 { "error": {
      "root_cause": [
           {
               "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
               "reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mapping : {properties={created={type=date, format=x},
```

Right now I don't really know what to do. Searching on the interwebz basically only talks about the formatting section and not much about configuring or creating the index. Do I need a plugin for elasticsearch to handle date?

Comment: You got the error while creating the mapping because in json you wrote `mapping` which should be actually `mappings`

Answer (score 0):

JSON (which is the data format of ElasticSearch) doesn't have an explicit format for date, they are always treated as strings, even when delivered in another way.

So, actually, if you do NOT specify a format for date, this option is taken into consideration: "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis", which is epoch millis - which again is correct in your case.

That's why everybody is just talking about formatting and not converting ;)

Comment: Alright, so elasticsearch don't understand date. My question then should probably be how can I make a Kibana Visualisation using a x-axis as "Date Histogram", because right now it says that there is "No Compatible Fields". I'm using kibana and elasticsearch 6.5.1

Comment: that's probably right; i am no big Kibana expert though. You need to change the mapping of string to date in elastic; Kibana then automatically recognized it as a date field. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html should get you going.

Comment: Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes, so here's another comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/mapping-date-format.html#custom-date-formats

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

It appears that the `curl` command I made had an error in the `dbname` used and the name used in the mapper. There was an error on the JSON too, making it harder to understand. It is now working gracefully. I also changed the `format` to `epoch_millis` instead of `x`.

Now it works like a charm and made my first dashboard in Kibana.